# WooCoommerce custom endpoint - Enable auth protection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have defined the following custom endpoint for woocommerce:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'custom_endpoint' );

function custom_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route( 'wc/v3', 'my_custom_endpoint', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'return_value',
    ) );
}

function return_value() {
    return "this is my custom endpoint!";
}
```

However, this endpoint is also accessible if I'm not authenticated using the ck and cs.

How can I protect it the same way all other, default endpoints of the WooCommerce API are protected? (I would prefer not needing another auth plugin for this to work, but to access it with the standard WooCommerce auth keys instead).

Thanks!

Comment: As raju_eww pointed, you can use [permissions callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback) to restrict your endpoint from being accessed without sending an authenticated request. Or is it not what you want? And you don't have to use [JWT](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) - it's just an example plugin which one can use to [authenticate their requests](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/).. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ actually yes, it worked out! Makes sense that the plugin is not necessarily required, as it's just another way of authenticating... One more question: do you know how I can change the 401 forbidden status code when an unauthorized user tries to access the endpoint to a 404 error?

Comment: You could `return new WP_Error( 'rest_404', 'Your custom message', array( 'status' => 404 ) );` from the permissions callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello use `permission_callback` with `JWT Authentication for WP REST API` plugin so it will work fine.

Steps :

1) Install `JWT Authentication for WP REST API` plugin
2) Set `permission_callback`

Below code will work well after `JWT Authentication for WP REST API` plugin installation

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'custom_endpoint');
function custom_endpoint(){
  register_rest_route('wc/v3', 'my_custom_endpoint', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'return_value',
    'permission_callback' => function($request){      
      return is_user_logged_in();
    }
  ));
}

function return_value(){
    return "this is my custom endpoint!";
}
```

for more information please check `JWT Authentication for WP REST API` documentation.

Checked and works well.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to do it without another plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie authentication is the standard authentication method included with WordPress. When you log in to your dashboard, this sets up the cookies correctly for you, so plugin and theme developers need only to have a logged-in user.

As an example, this is how the built-in Javascript client creates the nonce:

```
<?php
wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'wpApiSettings', array(
    'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
) );
```

This is then used in the base model:

```
options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce);

    if (beforeSend) {
        return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

Here is an example of editing the title of a post, using jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/posts/1',
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
    },
    data:{
        'title' : 'Hello Moon'
    }
} ).done( function ( response ) {
    console.log( response );
} );
```

Note that you do not need to verify that the nonce is valid inside your custom end point. This is automatically done for you in
rest_cookie_check_errors()

**Woocommerce API**

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#authentication-over-https

> While cookie authentication is the only authentication mechanism
>   available natively within WordPress, plugins may be added to support
>   alternative modes of authentication that will work from remote
>   applications.

As Per Official Document : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any insights into how I can re-use the woocommerce api authentication for custom endpoints?